# Is it possible to combine wildcards with other text or wildcards between slashes as part of a get() or exists() path in Firestore Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have documents in Firestore where the ID is a combination of other collection and document IDs which I would like to retrieve or check the existence of in my security rules, but I can't find a syntax that the rules editor likes or that pass as expected.

I've tried e.g.

`exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/relationships/$(collection)\_users/\_/$(document)_$(request.auth.uid))`

but the rules editor gives the following two errors:

> Error saving rules - Line XX: Unexpected '_users'.
>
> error: Unexpected '_' for the one in the last segment

and although I don't get an error from the editor for entering

`exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/relationships/$(collection + '\_users')/\_/$(document + '_' + request.auth.uid))`

it doesn't work as expected.

Rules also doesn't like `/$(collection)$(document)/`, and as far as I can tell, variables can't be manually declared in rules functions either to pass to `get()` and `exists()`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection}/{document} {
      allow read: if userHasAccess(collection, document)
    }
  }
}

function userHasAccess(collection, document) {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/relationships/$(collection)_users/_/$(document)_$(request.auth.uid))
}
```

I expect that the rules above would allow a user with id '0' to read the document at path `/databases/{database}/documents/things/thing1` if another document exists at `/databases/{database}/documents/relationships/things_users/_/thing1_0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in paths, but you can't concatenate variables with each other to form a path segment when defining a path using its bare slash notation. The variable must contain the entire path segment between slashes.

What you can do instead is build a string using [string concatenation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String), then convert that into a path object using [path()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path.html).  So you can essentially say:

```
exists(path(some + path + concatenation))
```